# Multi group with multi column in crystalreport

Tags: crystal-reports, grouping

I have table like this:

| emp_Id | salary_type | salary_value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| e-001 | addition | 2.00 |
| e-001 | addition | 0.50 |
| e-001 | deduction | -0.10 |
| e-002 | addition | 2.50 |
| e-002 | addition | 1.50 |
| e-002 | deduction | 0.00 |
| e-003 | addition | 4.00 |
| e-003 | deduction | -0.50 |
| e-003 | deduction | -0.25 |

I want to display in crystal report like this:
[crystalreport display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZDp2.jpg)

how to configure the crystalreport? can anyone help me? thank you.

Comment: What is the logic for associating a deduction to a particular addition row?

Comment: hi, I have found the answer. I use subreport and it works. thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use subreport and it works perfectly.